# Configuración de routing en PHP y Apache2, error: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, apache2

Tengo un sistema de Routing de PHP que funciona bien en local vagrant, pero cuando lo subo a mi apache2 y voy a algún enlace que vaya más allá de página de inicio (ej. `https://www.myurl.com/about`) me da error:

> The requested URL /about was not found on this server

La página de inicio funciona bien. A continuación dejo los bloques de mi código (lo dejo todo porque no tengo ni idea de donde puede haber el error que Apache no tolera).

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**index.php**

```
require Router::load('routes.php')->direct(Request::uri());
```

**routes.php**

```
$router->define(
    "home" => 'controllers/home.php',
    "blog" => 'controllers/blog.php',
    "about" => 'controllers/about.php',
);
```

Comment: Tal cual como lo mencionas, solo toca cambiar None por All <Directory /var/www/> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: Excelente, he trabajado con Laravel y no me funcionaba el GET. Con esto fue solucionado, solamente reinicie el servidor y volví a entrar a la URL y listo! Gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Después de 1 día entero intentando modificar mi .htaccess y sistema de routing he averiguado la solución: tenía que ir a mi archivo `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Y cambiar la palabra `None` este código:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Por por la palabra `All` para que quede así:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Y finalmente:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Ese cambio consiste en cambiar la palabra `None` por `All` en `AllowOverride`. Eso deja a que el archivo `.htaccess` cambie el routing.  Anteriormente en una página había leído que ese cambio permite que .htaccess deje de ser ignorado, pero pensé que eso ya lo tenía bien, porque tenía en mi `.htaccess` una redirección a `https` y `www.` y me funcionaba.

Pues resulta que `https` y `www.` no son ignorados con o sin esa modificación pero **sin `AllowOverride All` el routing en Apache2 no va a funcionar.**