# Apache - URLS no me funcionan en local (windows + apache 2.4)

Tags: php, php7, apache2

Tengo una instalación en local en Windows con Apache 2.4 y PHP 7.2.3. Está instalado sin usar Xampp o similares, los instalé en su día por separado.

Tengo diversos proyectos de Laravel funcionando en local y todo perfectamente, pero tengo un pequeño proyecto que es muy simple con PHP 7 sin framework, son 4 páginas estáticas.

Y los links que genero dentro de la url son de este estilo `url + acción`, el virtualhost que tengo en local es `ejemplo.local`, con lo que genero URLs del tipo `http://ejemplo.local/ofertas` o bien `http://ejemplo.local/marcas`.

El mismo código si lo subo al servidor de producción funciona, si lo pruebo en local este tipo de URLs me da un error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

El virtualhost que tengo configurado en Apache es éste:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/landings/coches/"
ServerName ejemplo.local
ServerAlias www.ejemplo.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Y si hago un `phpinfo()` como datos destacables, veo lo siguiente

> **Loaded Modules**    core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_php7 mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authn_socache mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cache_socache mod_cern_meta mod_cgi mod_dav_lock mod_dir mod_env mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_cache_disk mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_proxy mod_proxy_ajp **mod_rewrite** mod_sed mod_session mod_setenvif mod_socache_dbm mod_socache_memcache mod_socache_redis mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status mod_version mod_vhost_alias mod_xml2enc

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el contenido de `.htaccess`?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/100585/81450

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas dar de alta en el archivo hosts de Windows la dirección 127.0.0.1    ejemplo.local

El archivo está ubicado en `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

Y en el vhost ponerlo así:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/landings/coches"
    ServerName ejemplo.local
    ServerAlias *.ejemplo.local
    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/landings/coches">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Lo más probable es que tú falla esté en el server alias que le pones www

Comment: Creo que deberías marcar como correcta la respuesta de @ErikCuaquira. Ésta ha sido la última en ser redactada y es una copia de su contenido. Según la respuesta/comentario que has publicado sólo necesitabas habilitar el uso de `mod_rewrite` con `AllowOverride` como te indiqué en la mía.

Answer (score 2):

Para comprobar el funcionamiento en local, no está de más hacer un `ping` a `ejemplo.local` y debe retornar `127.0.0.1` con el nombre de tu equipo local.

```
ping ejemplo.local
```

Tampoco está de más verificar que dentro de tu xampp tengas a `localhost` configurado en un `<VirtualHost>`. Esto evita redirecciones a otros sitios locales.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

En tu `<VirtualHost>`, si cuentas con el módulo `mod_rewrite`, deberías considerar agregar la regla `Require all granted`, aunque podrías omitirla ya que como indicas en tu pregunta no usas redirecciones, pero te puede ser útil.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/landings/coches/"
  ServerName ejemplo.local
  ServerAlias www.ejemplo.local
  <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/landings/coches/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Si pruebas estas 3 consideraciones sencillas y aún no encuentras solución, puedo ahondar en el tema para encontrar el error. Pero prueba esto inicialmente.

Comment: Mi +1, aunque basta con usar `AllowOverride FileInfo`, no es necesario habilitar todo.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia. Siempre se aprende algo nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Para que el módulo `mod_rewrite` funcione necesitas tener habilitado la directiva `FileInfo` de [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#allowoverride) en una sección [`Directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#directory):

> **FileInfo**
>
> Allow use of the directives controlling document types, **`mod_rewrite`** directives (`RewriteEngine`, `RewriteOptions`, `RewriteBase`, `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule`) and `Action` from `mod_actions`.
>
> Only available in `<Directory>` sections
>
> `AllowOverride` is valid only in `<Directory>` sections specified without regular expressions, not in `<Location>`, `<DirectoryMatch>` or `<Files>` sections.

En castellano:

> **FileInfo**
>
> Permite el uso de directivas que controlen los tipos de documentos, las directivas de **`mod_rewrite`** (`RewriteEngine`, `RewriteOptions`, `RewriteBase`, `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule`) y `Action` de `mod_actions`.
>
> Solo está disponible en secciones `<Directory>`
>
> `AllowOverride` es válido únicamente en secciones `<Directory>` sin expresiones regulares, no en secciones `<Location>`, `<DirectoryMatch>` o `<Files>`.

---

Un ejemplo de uso usando el directorio de tu proyecto:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/landings/coches/">
    AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

Comment: Por primera vez me entero del motivo por el que se usa allowoverride. Es también la primera vez que alguien lo explica con tanto detalle ,alguna que otra vez probé a ponerlo en virtualhost y no funcionó, ahora entiendo el por que. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

ha sido poner esto en el vhost y funcionar.

```
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/landings/coches">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez me pasó algo similar... la verdad lo solucioné utilizando Wamp... jaja no entendí bien porque en Wamp si funcionaba y en Xampp no... talvez te funcione igualmente así, pruébalo.